# Match String version of Object element to Object element itself

Tags: c#

I'm having an instance where I have an object that looks similar to this:

```
public class answerObject
{
    public string Q1 { get; set; }
    public string Q2 { get; set; }
    public string Q3 { get; set; }
    public string Q4 { get; set; }
    public string Q5 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Q80 { get; set; }
}
```

The questions themselves look like this:

```
public class questionObject
{
    public string DataMember { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The DataMember string carries a string version of the answer object element.  So, if I have question 1 have a datamember of "Q1" then I want it to fill in answerObject.Q1 and so on.  Right now I have a lengthy switch statement to solve this, but there has to be a more efficient way to do this.

```
switch(DataMember) {
    case "Q1":
        answerObject.Q1 = answerValue;
        break;
    case "Q2":
        answerObject.Q2 = answerValue;
        break;
    ....
};
```

I've researched for a few hours and didn't come up with anything.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: so ? you just have five `case` statements.it's reasonable I think...

Comment: Well, It's actually 80, as there are 80 question answers in the answer object.  I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reflection` for that but <strike>I would keep using the `switch/case`</strike>:

```
var property = typeof(answerObject).GetProperty(DataMember);

if(property != null) property.SetValue(yourInstance, answerValue);
```

After your edit using `Reflection` makes more sense.Anyway you can also put this code into an extension method:

```
public static void SetAnswer(this answerObject instance, string question, string value)
{
    var property = typeof(answerObject).GetProperty(question);

    if (property != null) property.SetValue(instance, value);
    else { // throw exception or display a message }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object - make your **Questions** a dictionary and set the string *Q1*, *Q2*, etc. as key (your `DataMember` would later be filled with one of the keys). Then to assign the question just use the already set *DataMember* and the [item property of the Dictionary object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The code could look like this:

```
public class QuestionObject
{
    public string DataMember { get; set; }
    public String Answer { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerObject
{
    public Dictionary<String, String> Questions { get; set; }

    public AnswerObject()
    {
        Questions = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        // init the question keys
        Enumerable.Range(1, 80).ToList().ForEach(index =>
        {
            Questions.Add(String.Format("Q{0}", index), String.Empty);
        });
    }
}
```

And the usage looks like this:

```
var question = new QuestionObject();
var answer = new AnswerObject();

question.DataMember = @"Q75";
// set the question = the same as the switch/case
answer.Questions[question.DataMember] = @"and the answer is ...";
```